# How to split the RFH2 (String) from the payload (byte[]) of a MQ-Series Dead Letter in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, ibm-mq, mq

**My assignment:** I have a queue-system provided by the IBM MQ-Series. I need to get all messages of a "Dead-Letter-Queue". The RFH2-Header and the original payload were assembled in the Dead-Letter. I the original payload is mostly a zip-file or string. Since there is the possibilty of the payload being a zip-file, I need to save the payload as a byte[] in java. The RFH2 should be a Linked HashMap.

**What I've got so far:**

```
    public ZMessageDTO(final ZMessageType messageType, MQMessage message) throws ZDAEQException {
        this.mqMessage = message;
        this.messageType = messageType;

        List<byte[]> payloadRFH2List = this.split("</usr>".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        rfh2 = getRFH2OfXMLBytes(payloadRFH2List.get(0));
        payload = payloadRFH2List.get(1);
    }

    public boolean isMatch(byte[] pattern, byte[] input, int pos) {
        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
            if (pattern[i] != input[pos + i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

public List<byte[]> split(byte[] pattern) throws ZDAEQException {
    try {
        byte[] input = new byte[(int) mqMessage.getMessageLength()];

        for (int i = 0; i < (int) mqMessage.getMessageLength(); i++) {
            input[i] = mqMessage.readByte();
        }
        List<byte[]> l = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
        int blockStart = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (isMatch(pattern, input, i)) {
                l.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(input, blockStart, i));
                blockStart = i + pattern.length;
                i = blockStart;
            }
        }
        l.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(input, blockStart, input.length));
        return l;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ZDAEQException("Couldn't split dead letter" + e);
    }
}
```

**What happens by now:**
If I create a new Message out of the data a get, it cuts the rfh2 by the 2066th char. If i call the original payload, I get a NullPointer.

**What's the crux?**
As I mentionend in the assignment, the RFH2 and the original payload are both assembled in the "Dead-Letter-Payload" (I hope you unterstand what I'm trying to tell). What I tried so far, is to search the payload for the `</usr>`-ending tag and save the two parts. I saved the first part as a String and the second part as a byte[]. I have absolutely no Idea if this works or not.

**My question:**
Is it possible to split the Dead-Letter-Payload in two parts and save the first one as a string, and the second one as a byte[]?

Comment: I'm not a Java programmer, but can't you use the MQHeaderIterator or MQHeaderList? See http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030880_.htm - that page has various other helpful things that I suspect you need.

Answer (score 1):

The MQRFH2 structure is very complex.  If you don't understand it then why aren't you using the [MQRFH2](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/headers/MQRFH2.html) class?

IBM provides the MQRFH2 class so that developers don't have to deal with the structure.

i.e.

```
mqMsg.seek(0);
MQRFH2 rfh2 = new MQRFH2(mqMsg);
byte[] data = new byte[mqMsg.getDataLength()];
mqMsg.readFully(data);
System.out.println("Message data: "+new String(data));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get these three Errors:
MQJE001: Beendigungscode '1', Ursache '2142'.
MQJE001: Beendigungscode '2', Ursache '2195'.
MQJE001: Beendigungscode '2', Ursache '2195'.
I googled them but they don't seem to be correct for my case.

It seems special that I create an instance of MQRFH2 but never use it.